# CHMOD 0777 and back to 0644

Tags: php

I have a cron script that needs to write some html into a file.

The file that needs to have HTML written is in public_html dir and the script in a different location, just above that dir. If I CHMOD manually everything works, but I don not want to leave it as 0777 or keep on doing it manually, so I wanted to make my script to do it for me.

```
ob_start();

// build my HTML

$myHTML = ob_get_clean();

// CODE TO SAVE INTO INCLUDE <<<

$filename = 'home/public_html/file.php';

if (is_writable($filename)) {

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
         mail("support@domain.com", "Failed to create include", "Script failed to create include", "From: Support <support@domain.com>");
    exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, ($myHTML)) === FALSE) {
       mail("support@domain.com", "Failed to create include", "Script failed to create include", "From: Support <support@domain.com>");
    exit;
    }

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    mail("support@domain.com", "Failed to create include", "Script failed to create include", "From: Support <support@domain.com>");
    exit;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to work. Why?

Comment: Why not just set the umask instead of performing these backflips?

Comment: What is the configuration of the server? Specifically which user is the webserver, the scripts and the cronjobs running under?

Comment: And the other two? Just chown it after writing to the normal user.

Comment: I don't get the point of this. Why do you need to change the permission twice within the same request ? If your script has the permission to change these, it also has the permission to write in it. Why switching it to 777 just to write in it ?

Comment: @Touki -- Good point. Clearly my script does not. What shall I do?

Comment: Several points. Yet, does your file exists or not ? If it does, you have nothing to deal with permissions if your script has `is_writable($file)` permissions. If it doesn't, when generating a file from a script, you'll get `0644` permissions as well as `UID/GID` (from the script) of the generated file. If you run it from root, you'd better `chgrp(www-data)` and `chown(www-data)`

Comment: @Touki --  Yes the file exists. I just updated my original post with the entire code, how I have it.

Comment: This looks like an absolute path `home/public_html/` are you sure you didn't mispell it ? Can you `var_dump(file_exists($filename))` ? Then maybe with `var_dump(file_put_contents($filename,$myHTML))`

Comment: That was it!  Embarrassing, I forgot that my server was migrated and the path has changed... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @santa Great new then. Never forget to check if the file exists before trying to write in it. Posting comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an absolute path `home/public_html/` are you sure you didn't mispell it ?
You can

```
var_dump(file_exists($filename))
```

If `true` is returned then you can try
With

```
var_dump(file_put_contents($filename,$myHTML))
```

You can check how much bytes you've written in it.
If `false` is returned this means you're having a permission issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to have write permission to a file before you can write changes to the permissions.

Comment: Actually, you have to be the owner.